# log- and z-transforming my data in R

Tags: r

I'm preparing my data for a PCA, for which I need to standardize it. I've been following someone else's code in `vegan` but am not getting a mean of zero and SD of 1, as I should be.

I'm using a data set called musci which has 13 variables, three of which are labels to identify my data.

```
log.musci<-log(musci[,4:13],10)
stand.musci<-decostand(log.musci,method="standardize",MARGIN=2)
```

When I then check for mean=0 and SD=1...

```
colMeans(stand.musci)
sapply(stand.musci,sd)
```

I get mean values ranging from -8.9 to 3.8 and SD values are just listed as NA (for every data point in my data set rather than for each variable). If I leave out the last variable in my standardization, i.e.

```
log.musci<-log(musci[,4:12],10)
```

the means don't change, but the SDs now all have a value of 1.

Any ideas of where I've gone wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: you can try `?scale` from base R

Comment: I've tried that too, to no avail.

Comment: what isn't working when you do that?  By default it just substracts the mean and divides by the sd

Comment: the command run, but it's not giving me a mean of 0 and an sd of 1 (I pretty much get the same output as outlined in my question above). Am I wrong to standardize log-transformed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data is likely a matrix.

```
## Sample data
dat <- as.matrix(data.frame(a=rnorm(100, 10, 4), b=rexp(100, 0.4)))
```

So, either convert to a `data.frame` and use `sapply` to operate on columns

```
dat <- data.frame(dat)
scaled <- sapply(dat, scale)
colMeans(scaled)
#             a             b 
# -2.307095e-16  2.164935e-17 
apply(scaled, 2, sd)
# a b 
# 1 1
```

or use `apply` to do columnwise operations

```
scaled <- apply(dat, 2, scale)
```

Comment: Ok, so that works.. Thanks! But I thought the means should have been 0 in order for my data to be standardized?

Comment: those numbers are 0 as far as R is concerned, `all.equal(1e-16, 0) # TRUE`

Comment: I'm very new to R (and never really had a head for statistics), but I feel like I should be able to get this without issues. After all it is still quite a simple task!

Comment: Thanks for translating R for me, now I feel like a total idiot ^.^

Comment: I'm chuffed, so glad it worked! time to move on to harder things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A z-transformation is quite easy to do manually.
See below using a random string of data.

```
data <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
data
mean(data)
sd(data)
z <- ((data - mean(data))/(sd(data)))
z
mean(z) == 0
sd(z) == 1
```

The logarithm transformation (assuming you mean a natural logarithm) is done using the log() function.

```
log(data)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: when I try that I get an error message `in mean.default(data) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: @Anna this has to do with the format of your data. So for the above example if you type class(data) it will show as numeric. If it is not numeric you need to cast the type as numeric by using something like data <- as.numeric(data)